# Get SMB hostnames with Java

Tags: java, smb, jcifs

I want to make an Android app that browses files in the shared network.

Given a PC name, i.e `DESKTOP-T6Y766Y` I can browse the files

(with JCIFS library: `new SmbFile("smb://DESKTOP-T6Y766Y/...")`).

But I want to have the user to choose a PC from the shared ones in the local network.

**For clarification:** I marked in red the Strings I want my code to get:
[image]

I tried to use JCIFS library using this code:

```
SmbFile[] domains;
        domains = (new SmbFile("smb://")).listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < domains4.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(domains[i]);
        }
```

But it doesn't work:

`jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect to server
java.net.UnknownHostException: ..__MSBROWSE__.<01>`